# How to send the JSon object in the value field of input element

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I need to pass the user-selected values in the JSON format into my params.

Below is my code:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="employees[]" value={emp_id: 
    ${employee.employeeId}, employee_type:${employee.type}}/>
    Employee - ${employee.memberId} - ${employee.name}
</label>
```

I am not getting as a JSON object with the above code.

Please suggest me how I can fix this.

Comment: grails, goovy, gsp - one or all of those I assume - Not sure where the JavaScript is

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JSON notation there.

Something like:

GSP:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="employees" value='{"emp_id":"${employee.employeeId}", "employee_type":"${employee.type}"}'/>
```

Controller:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()

def saveAction() {
  def valueJson = slurper.parseText params.employees
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
I tried this but I am getting 'value' as a String. I need it to be JSON Object.

Comment: in your case you have to parse json yourself. see update.....